# Rewrite rules : forgetting a query string in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this in my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z\-_]+)(/)?  index.php?action=view&type=page&page=$1&%1 [L]
```

But when I put this in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8888/myapp/test%20doc
```

The url is transformed into:

```
index.php?action=view&type=page&page=test
```

Why shouldn't I get:

```
index.php?action=view&type=page&page=test%20doc ?
```

Comment: space isn't part of your pattern ....

Comment: Do you mean to be testing with the url: `http://localhost:8888/myapp/test?doc`

Comment: @Orangepill why do you mean by space ? Btw, I have edited my post I would like to get `index.php?action=view&type=page&page=test%20doc`

Comment: %20 == space ... try changing pattern to `^([0-9A-Za-z\-_ ]+)(/)?`

Comment: @Orangepill white space in `0-9A-Za-z\-_ ` is not recognized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For readability, remove the `RewriteCond` and add the QSA (Query String Append) flag to your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule     ^([\w-]+)/?    index.php?action=view&type=page&page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The url you are testing with (`http://localhost:8888/myapp/test%20doc`) doesn't have a query string. Do you mean to test with:

```
http://localhost:8888/myapp/test?doc
```

**Edit**

You're problem has nothing to do with query strings. Only the fact that you haven't matched the space character in your character class and you are intending to. Simply add a space to your character class. This should also work for you:

```
^([ \w-]+)/?
```

The `\w` is just a shorthand for `0-9A-Za-z_`

Comment: I have edited my post because I mistook , in fact I would like to get index.php?action=view&type=page&page=test%20doc

Comment: white space in `^([ \w-]+)/?` is not recognized

Comment: @user1611830 What do you mean be not recognized? It might break syntax highlighting in an editor, but it should work fine as far as Apache is concerned.

Comment: @user1611830 Hmm... Interesting. As far as I know the space character doesn't need to be escaped, but if it works, maybe I need to read up on that a bit. Either way, I'm glad you got it working. Cheers!